# JavaScript style: don't use wrapper objects for primitive types

Tags: javascript, object, coding-style, wrapper, primitive

In the Google JavaScript style guide, it says not to use wrapper objects for primitive types. It says it's "dangerous" to do so. To prove its point, it uses the example:

```
var x = new Boolean(false);
if (x) {
  alert('hi');  // Shows 'hi'.
}
```

OK, I give up. Why is the if code being executed here?

Comment: Because `Boolean(false) === !(new Boolean(false))`. And `Boolean(false) === new Boolean(false).valueOf()`.

Comment: @katspaugh: that makes it much clearer -- thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because every variable that is `typeof` `Object` is truthy and wrappers are objects.

Comment: So basically you're saying that x is _not_ being assigned the value false as I thought it was. It's being assigned an "object", which evaluates to true.

Comment: Yes, an object that wraps the value, but as it is an object, it is truthy.

Comment: `typeof null` -> "object", `!!null` -> false. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe nulls are falsy objects and a rather important exception to the above stated absolute rule.

Comment: @Patrick `null` isn't an object.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18808270/894284).

Comment: @MattFenwick I should have just said "nulls are falsy" and excluded the word "objects". Otherwise, I believe my comment still makes sense in context. Just because you have an `x` such that `typeof x` yields `"object"` is not a valid way to check that `x` is truthy.

Answer (score 12):

`if(x)` will run if `x` is truthy.

`x` is truthy if it's not falsey.

x is falsey if x is `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `false`

So since `new Boolean(false)` is an `Object` and an `Object` is truthy, the block runs

Answer (score 2):

In the `if(x)` case, it's actually evaluating the default Boolean of the object named and not its value of `false`.

So be careful using `Boolean` objects instead of `Boolean` values. =)

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses a Boolean object. The Boolean object is false, yet `console.log("Found")` still executes because an object is always considered true inside a conditional statement. It doesn’t matter that the object represents false; it’s an object, so it evaluates to true.

```
var found = new Boolean(false);
if (found) 
{    console.log("Found");
       // this executes
}
```